# Web API Http Request Interception - Simple Injector with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, simple-injector

I want to create an interface with Simple Injector, but [this code](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html) looks like it's only for .NET Framework. Does such a code sample exist for core?

Comment: What make you think that this code is for Framework only and not for Core? Have you try to run it with Core? What is a target of `SimpleInjector` (.Net Framework, .Net Core or .Net Standard)?

Comment: Take a look at the [integration guide](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html) and look for the Castle Dynamic Proxy integration. Castle will work under .NET Core.

Comment: Hi @vasily.sib:  When I added the code to my solution, the using references for anything under  System.Runtime.Remoting was invalid.  When I looked it up, the newest framework it's available (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.1) in is .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Steven:  Thank you. I think I may be confusing Interceptors with HttpFilters.  What I'd like to do is intercept an HTTP call to check authorization and cached data.  Am i barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which level you need the request to be intercepted. ASP.NET Core contains middleware that allows intercepting requests before and after they execute the controller. If that's the level you need, google on how to apply middleware (also see the Simple Injector docs). If you need to intercept on a deeper level (when a controller calls into the business layer) [interceptors or decorators](https://simpleinjector.org/aop) are ideal.